# Fetching Data from Multiple Birt Report into a single BIRT Report

Tags: postgresql, reporting-services, birt, merging-data

I have created multiple Reports and need to create a final report which will contain the data from these multiple reports.

The following is my situation:

```
  Report A:
  Column        Column1     Column2     Column3     Column4      Calucation
   Row-A            a1          a2          a3          a4          CalA.A
   Row-B            b1          b2          b3          b4          CalB.A
   Row-C            c1          c2          c3          c4          CalC.A  


  Report B:
  Column        Column1     Column2     Column3     Column4     Calucation
   Row-A            a1          a2          a3          a4          CalA.B
   Row-B            b1          b2          b3          b4          CalB.B
   Row-C            c1          c2          c3          c4          CalC.B


  Report Aggregated
  Column        Column1     Column2     Total
   Row-A          CalA.A    CalA.B      Total.A
   Row-B          CalB.A    CalB.B      Total.B
   Row-C          CalC.A    CalC.B      Total.C
```

Here as seen Report A and Report B is calculated from a postgres DB.

The Aggregated Report needs to fetch the data calulated in Report A and Report B.

Please help me find a way where I can pass the data from these Multiple reports into the final report.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the calculation in the data set and not in the table where you are displaying your data, if you are doing this right now (double click the data set: Computed Columns).

Then you can export your data set (and the data source) to a library (right click your data set: Export to Library...) and reuse the data set from the new library in you first reports and also your aggregated report.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by Joining the two Tables:

```
Joined Table ==> (Aggregated table)
Column   P.Key    Column-1     Column-2       Total
 Row-A    100      CalA.A       CalA.B      Total.A
 Row-B    101      CalB.A       CalB.B      Total.B
 Row-C    102      CalC.A       CalC.B      Total.C
```

Then I binded this joined table to my required grid on the report and displayed the values as required.

Hope this helps someone else in need.

Cheers :)